# Build C++ project with makefile (without Cmake) and run tests using Jenkins

Tags: c++, jenkins, makefile, continuous-integration

I am trying to build my makefile C++ project using Jenkins.
See project structure below. Project is on a bitbucket repository and job profile is set Freestyle Project.

Project is successfully built on Jenkins server however it looks like it just uploads the project from repository to its workspace and says "Finshed with success" but does not run a makefile. 
Console output:

```
Checking out Revision 6720229e2d82a9e958f69afabe361c65d1647398 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f 6720229e2d82a9e958f69afabe361c65d1647398
Commit message: "My commit"
> git rev-list --no-walk 084977a421fc8fb064297f64407e2d137a1b32a1 # timeout=10
Finished: SUCCESS
```

On my local however both test and main projects are built successfully with make.

**Basically there are two questions:**

1. How to build my project (including the test one) with Makefile on Jenkins? (i.e. how to run a make command on Jenkins). I do not want to use a Cmake. Is it possible?
2. If both projects built successfully, how to run the test project and see test results in console/write to file in Jenkins?

My project structure:

```
MyProject
|+src/     <-- source files main project
|+include/  <-- header files main project
|+bin/     <-- binaries main project
|+test/    <-- test project

|~test/
    | |+bin/ <-- test binaries
    | |+gtest/ <-- gtest headers
    | |+lib/ <-- gtest binaries
    | |-test.cpp <-- test source

|-Makefile
```

My Makefile:

```
# Compiler options and variables def
CC=g++
CPPFLAGS= -c -Wall  
GFLAGS = -g 

INC_DIR = include  
INC_DIR_TEST = test

TST += \
    *.cpp
VPATH += test/ 

TESTLIB += \
    *.a

SRC += \
    *.cpp

BIN = bin

TSTBIN = test/bin


# build

all: program test


OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp, $(BIN)/%.o, $(SRC))

TSTOBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp, $(TSTBIN)/%.o, $(TST))

program: $(OBJ) 
    $(CC) $(GFLAGS) $? -o $@ 

test: $(TSTOBJ) $(TESTLIB) $(BIN)/file1.o $(BIN)/file2.o 
    $(CC) $(GFLAGS) $(TESTLIB) $(BIN)/file1.o $(BIN)/file2.o $< -o $@

$(BIN)/%.o: src/%.cpp 
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(INC_DIR) $< -o $@ 

$(TSTBIN)/%.o: test/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(INC_DIR_TEST) -I$(INC_DIR) $< -o $@ 

clean:
    rm *.o *.exe bin/*.o test/bin/*.o
```

**Update:**

As I understand, this type of project has to be marked as pipeline rather than freestyle project that will allow to choose a build tool and run shell command from `Jenkinsfile` file that facilitates considerably the CI process.

However I cannot find any examples of building C++ project with make and GNU build tools. 
This is a `Jenkinsfile` example from [official documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/)

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker 'maven:3.3.3' }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering now how this should be modified in order to build a simplest C++ project with makefile. Am I on a right way?
Second question is still actual: how to run my gtests and record results in Jenkins after the make command works?

**Update:**

I have used a batchfile as it can be ran from java code in Jenkinsfile. Now my testing Jenkinsfile looks like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                echo 'building..'
                bat 'batchfile.cmd'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Batchfile code:

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin"

make
```

There are still some bugs but at least make command is ran and the commands from makefile are called.

So general conclusion:
As it looks like there is no any make plugin for jenkins, the pipeline stages can run a batchfile (or shell script for UNIX), and this batchfile can call make. Of course make has to be installed on a server and the path to environment variable has to be specified.

Maybe there are some better approaches or I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: What job profile are you using in Jenkins?(Free Style project or Pipeline) Kindly update the details on the questions.

Comment: @AmeyaVS Thank you, I have edited the question. Can you tell me, If it is a Pipeline, what is the fundamental difference? How do I write that pipeline script then (I need just two commands: {make} and {./test} basically. I think it can be an answer to both of my questions